# Why is the ProgressDialog not being dismissed, in this case?

Tags: android, progressdialog

There are a number of questions involving the lack of ability to dismiss a ProgressDialog, but none of them seem to cover my situation.

I have a Thread that runs a Runnable object that, when it completes, sends a message to a Handler object which I'm certain is sitting on the same thread as the ProgressDialog. The handler does this:

```
if(progressDialog != null){
    Log.w(TAG, "Progress dialog is dismissed");
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}else{
    Log.w(TAG, "Progress dialog is null");
}
```

I've done this a million times before, and it's worked. The ProgressDialog goes away. But, in one particular instance, it doesn't.

In this particular case, a ProgressDialog (we'll call uploadChangesDialog) is showing, then a particular Handler (uploadChangesHandler) is called. After dismissing the uploadChangesDialog, it does a check that, if true, starts a different ProgressDialog (refreshViewDialog) and a Runnable (refreshViewRunnable) in a Thread. However, when it's Handler is called (refreshViewHandler), it can't close the dialog. But it *does* log `Progress dialog is dismissed`.

This is particularly strange, because the refreshViewsRunnable is run when the Activity is started, too, but it can get rid of the dialog then, just fine. The progressDialog variable above is the only one of it's kind, which is supposed to hold whatever ProgressDialog is currently showing.

I've done this with AlertDialogs before, but they know how to close themselves, so if I'm doing something wrong, then I wouldn't have noticed.

In the onCreateDialog() method:

```
case DIALOG_REFRESH_VIEW:
    progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading details...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    return progressDialog;
```

Copied for each instance, with a different message. I did change it to all dialogs pointing to the same code, and setting the message in onPrepareDialog(), but that didn't change any behaviour.

In the UploadChangesRunnable:

```
public void run(){
    int result = 0;
    if(uploadChanges()){
        result = 1;
    }
    uploadChangesHandler.sendEmptyMessage(result);
}
```

And then in uploadChangesHandler:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg){
    if(progressDialog != null){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    if(msg.what == 0){
        showDialog(DIALOG_UPLOAD_CHANGES_FAILED); //This is an AlertDialog
    }else{
        //All this does is showDialog(DIALOG_REFRESH_VIEW) then run the thread.
        //This method is in the enclosing Activity class.
        refreshViewInThread();
    }
}
```

Finally, the refreshViewInThread method:

```
private void refreshViewInThread(){
    showDialog(DIALOG_REFRESH_VIEW);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new RefreshViewRunnable(refreshViewHandler));
    thread.start();
}
```

And the RefreshViewRunnable looks remarkably similar to the UploadChangesRunnable.

There must be some special case that makes me lose the link to my progressDialog, and the dialog that I'm dismissing is likely not the dialog that is showing, but I can't think of how that could be. Any ideas?

Comment: You have said at one point that your handler is making responding, but not making any changes to UI. Can it be that you start a new handler, but try to make changes from the one that was used before? Maybe you may move some functionality from handler that makes changes to graphics into runOnUiThread(Runnable)

Comment: @MocialovBoris: RefreshView was probably not the best name for me to choose. The RefreshViewRunnable just downloads the data for the page again, and the Handler updates the views with the new data. This works fine, which I believe means the handler must be in the UI thread. It's just that it also tries to dismiss the progressDialog, and fails at that.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that this is a context/handler issue. I had a similar problem, and decided to use interfaces/callbacks instead of Handler, and it fixed my problem.

However, you could try the following, where you see this: >> But it does log Progress dialog is dismissed.<< , add:

```
MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      progressDialog.dismiss();
      }
    });
```